# Como puedo eliminar una linea de un archivo txt desde Java

Tags: java

Tengo una duda y es como puedo eliminar una linea de un archivo txt desde Java
Solo tengo este código y no se como empezar

```
File file=new File("archivo.txt");
Josep;20;Sants
Maria;20;Sants
Angel;35;Nou Barris
Tengo esta info y seria  eliminar toda la linea
```

Comment: A falta de mayor explicación, ¿es necesario devolver ese mismo fichero modificado? Lo pregunto porque se me ocurre que puedes coger el fichero, trastrear con él quitando lo que no quieras y, devolver otro modificado. De esta forma no se altera el original.

Comment: Sí , hay que devolver el mismo fichero modificado

Comment: ¿Puedes poner algún ejemplo de qué es lo que hay que eliminar? ¿Algún patrón en especial?

Comment: Lo he puesto arrriba tengo esas lineas y quiero eliminar una linea entera de las que hay por ejemplo la segunda

Comment: Quizás te puedan servir los casos de los compañeros de SO en inglés: [aquí] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove-it), [o aquí] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211060/how-to-delete-or-remove-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file) [o también aquí] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035929/remove-a-specific-line-from-text-file). Esos son algunos ejemplos, en la comunidad se han hecho muchas preguntas parecidas.

Comment: Me dan error lo que me has pasado

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de error? Los links o lo que plantean?

Comment: Lo que plantean

Comment: La lectura puede hacerse de muchas formas según la versión de Java y si quiere hacer uso de librerías externas como Apache. Puedes usar StringBuffer para leer. Si el archivo es pequeño, lo lees todo (te saltas lo que no quieres) cierras el archivo, lo borras y lo vuelves a escribir, si el archivo es muy grande lo escribes en otro y borras el primero y el segundo lo renombras.